# How to show-hide Opera Browser Toolbar in Full Screen Mode

Tags: web, toolbar, fullscreen, show-hide, opera

Occasionally, I accidentally hit the cmd that removes the Opera Toolbar in Full Screen Mode. I always have difficulty finding a quick answer to resolve the issue, so I wanted to create a question and answer it for myself and others in the future.

Searching for a solution often leads to threads with answers that do not resolve the issue or lead to folks being confused, I hope this will be a quick reference to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

To Show-Hide the Opera Toolbar in Full-Screen mode, press Shift + CMD + F. Alternatively, you may find the option in the View Tab of the Opera Application, the option is called "Hide Toolbar in Fullscreen Mode" or "Show Toolbar in Fullscreen Mode".